# How to import a class defined in groovy script into another groovy

Tags: class, groovy, import

I have a created a groovy script which contains a class with some attributes and methods.  I have also created another groovy script in which a class is calling methods from the first groovy script but I am getting the error:

> Unable to resolve class

Also, both the scripts are under same package.  My question is how to access a class (attributes/methods) defined in a different script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@PackageScope` annotation above the method or attribute you wish to access in another class from the same package.  You can also add it to the class itself.